# AngularJS - dynamically add a template and invoke corresponding controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I want to append a template when the user presses a button. I also want to invoke the corresponding controller. Unfortunately I dont have any idea how to to that.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append your template and create a new scope for. 
Afterwards you just need to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) it in order to invoke the controller.

So after you have appended your template:

```
var new_scope = $scope.$new();
$compile( $tmpl ) ( new_scope );
```

That also invokes your controller

Answer (score 1):

Use a Routes Application:

```
var application = {};

var App = angular.module('application');

App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/products', { templateUrl: 'views/products/list.html', controller: ProductsControllers })
        .when('…', { templateUrl: '…', controller: ... });
}]);
```

After only link to "/products" for example.

Comment: Thank you but that is not what i need. I want to append a view to the app. I do not want to replace a view

Comment: @user3518571 You can have just one ng-view. So, you can change its content in several ways: ng-include, ng-switch or mapping different controllers and templates through the routeProvider.

Comment: @user3518571 This library can help you. Its uses the partials to append views, see in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: so there is no way to click a button, append a template to the view and invoke the corresponding controller?

Comment: @user3518571 its possible to have said in the above comments.